# N channel mosfet gate-source pin distance

Tags: pcb, mosfet, source

I bought a mosfet said to be rated 600V/5A, yet the gate and source pin are very close together (4,5 mm or something close to that). I've been told 230V traces on a PCB should be at the very least 6 to 8mm apart to prevent sparking. My conclusion was pins with different potential should naturally have that same distance. Is this MOSFET rating faulty or am I missing something out here?

Comment: I am glad you asked this question. The gate-to-source dielectric layer will break down (shorting gate to source and destroying the transistor) at a much lower voltage than 230V, so there is no need for greater spacing between gate and source. If you are designing something that uses 230V, please be careful. I think it is great for people to learn in a hands-on fashion, but 230V can cause shocks and burns and energetic sparks and so-on.

Answer (score 2):

The *gate and source* pins should not be more than about 20V or so different but this is  device dependent, check Vgs (max) in the datasheet; the voltage rating you are referring to is Vds (drain to source).

There is a [calculator](http://www.smps.us/pcbtracespacing.html) avaliable; for IPC-2221A, the 600V (DC or AC peak) clearance is 3mm (minimum).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how this is derived, but we use minimum distance=0.6+Vpeak×0.005, where distance is in mm.  5mm is actually pretty large if you have good isolation.